# bash - how do you sort within the lines of a text file

Tags: bash, sorting, text-files

Using the linux command `sort`, how do you sort the lines within a text file?

Normal `sort` swaps the lines until they're sorted while I want to swap the words within the lines until they're sorted.

Example:

Input.txt

```
z y x v t
c b a
```

Output.txt

```
t v x y z
a b c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `gnu awk` then it can be done in a single command using [`asort` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions):

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i]=$i; n=asort(c); 
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", c[i], (i<n?OFS:RS); delete c}' file

t v x y z
a b c
```

Answer (score 4):

To sort words within lines using `sort`,
you would need to read line by line,
and call `sort` once for each line.
It gets quite tricky though,
and in any case,
running one `sort` process for each line wouldn't be very efficient.

You could do better by using Perl (thanks [@glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for the awesome tip!):

```
perl -lape '$_ = qq/@{[sort @F]}/' file
```

Comment: With `echo $(printf ... | sort)`, you risk glob expansion, no? You could just do `printf ... | sort` instead.

Comment: `$line` itself is subject to pathname expansion.

Comment: @BenjaminW. the wrapping in `echo $(...)` is to turn the multiline result of `sort` back into a single line

Comment: Nope, now you are only writing a single line to `sort`, because `"$line"` isn't subject to word-splitting.

Comment: You need to split the line without exposing it to pathname expansion; either use `printf '%s\n' "$(read -a arr <<< "$line"; printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}" | sort)`, or turn pathname expansion off with `printf '%s\n' "$(set -f; printf '%s\n' $line | sort)"`.

Comment: @chepner thanks... I dropped that idea entirely, I'd rather resort to Perl for this.

Comment: Can be written as `perl -lape '$_="@{[sort @F]}"' file`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun way that actually uses the linux `sort` command (plus `xargs`):

`while read line; do xargs -n1 <<< $line | sort | xargs; done < input.txt`

Now, this makes several assumptions (which are probably not always true), but the main idea is `xargs -n1` takes all the tokens in a line and emits them on separate lines in stdout.  This output gets piped through `sort` and then a final `xargs` *with no arguments* puts them all back into a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a magic switch but found my own solution more intuitive:

```
$ line="102 103 101 102 101"
$ echo $(echo "${line}"|sed 's/\W\+/\n/g'|sort -un)
101 102 103
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little awkward, but this uses only a basic `sort` command, so it's perhaps a little more portable than something that requires GNU sort:

```
while read -r -a line; do
  printf "%s " $(sort <<<"$(printf '%s\n' "${line[@]}")")
  echo
done < input.txt
```

The `echo` is included to insert a newline, which `printf` doesn't include by default.

Comment: This is subject to globbing: if I have files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` in the current directory and one of the words in `input.txt` is `f?.txt`, it'll expand to `f1.txt f2.txt`.

Comment: Something like `sort <<< "$(printf '%s\n' "${line[@]}")" | paste -s -d ' '` might work, assuming that the words are separated by a single space each.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried various ways to solve this (involving, e.g., GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and/or xargs) I found a simple way to do this, using only [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/):

```
split -l 1 --filter 'tr " " "\n" | sort | paste -s -d " "' \
in.txt > out.txt
```

Unfortunately, I think the `--filter` option to `split` is a GNU addition...